# How can i display points on map without cut?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need center 2 point on map, but when i use this code point are displayed cut :

```
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (int i=0;i<this.posicoesDispositivos.size();i++) {
            builder.include(this.posicoesDispositivos.get(i));
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        if (primeiraExecucao) {
            mMapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0));
            primeiraExecucao = false;
        }
```

**Image of display of this code:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0)
```

The last parameter that you are passing 0 is padding. You can change the value of padding to get the desired result such as

```
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20)
```

In this case 20 pixels will be added on all 4 sizes of bounding box.

Comment: Perfect i trying 18 but is not effective... with 40 works fine... thanks